# Asp.Net MVC 5 has no Add New Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I already searched my ItemTemplates in Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC\1033

It doesn't contain an AddController itemtemplate as in Asp.Net MVC 4.

I had a choice in other projects between adding WebApi Controller and WebController, somehow it dissapeared.

My menu in Tools - Customize seems to be okay...

I also repaired Visual Studio

Could there be anything else that's wrong?[image]

Comment: Try to unload and reload the project. Can you post the <ProjectTypeGuids> value (from the `.csproj`)

Comment: <ProjectGuid>{10998B1B-70BD-467E-9C84-B96FD48D1736}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>

Already setup a different MVC project, but had the same problem... So i don't think the problem is there

Comment: Isn't that menu context sensitive? If you select "New item" and then a new controller it should appear in that menu again if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Add new Item should have controller template...

Comment: I haven't changed any names, so i don't think any lowercases or so are changed.

Where is the ControllerTemplate of MVC 5 created then? (I have found the one for MVC 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, usually MVC5 **has** this entry in the context menu, if you right click this folder.
Try:
Right-Click "Controllers" folder > Add > New Scaffolded Item... > "Click here to go online and find more scaffolding extensions" and install "Microsoft Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC5 Scafolding".

If you do not have the "New Scaffolded Item" entry, just click "New Item", the link to the online library of extensions can also be found there.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Adding 'Controllers' folder to an empty project enables 'MVC Controller' option.  Right click on that folder.

Answer (score 2):

The project with Framwork 4.6.1 can find controller by: Right-Click "Controllers" folder > Add.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSJPb.png)